# Is it possible to reset the timeout of a delayed job in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have a delayed job that run a few steps. I would like to reset the timeout whenever a step is completed.
Is it possible?

For example

```rb
# config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 5.minutes
```

```rb
# app/jobs/my_process_job.rb
class MyProcessJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform
    `sleep 4m` # step 1
    # reset timeout
    `sleep 4m` # step 2
    puts 'done'
  end
end
```

Comment: Would it be an option to override the configuration to `9.minutes` just for this specific job class?

Comment: To me this just looks like you're doing too much in a single job and that the solution is to just have "sub-jobs" taht get scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how timeouts are implemented in [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/5ac5adea8d18325d0470eeebfa81227b1f5961e3/lib/delayed/worker.rb#L230), it's not possible to reset the timeout without modifying Delayed Job. However, you could do the following instead

```rb
# config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 10.minutes
```

```rb
# app/jobs/my_process_job.rb
class MyProcessJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform
    Timeout.timeout(5.minutes.to_i) {
      `sleep 4m` # step 1
    }

    Timeout.timeout(5.minutes.to_i) {
      `sleep 4m` # step 2
    }
    puts 'done'
  end
end
```